# How to turn on C# "Suggestion Messages" in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I've switched from Visual Studio to Visual Studio Code, and I really miss these suggestion messages:

[image]

I only get warnings and errors, and I wonder how could I enable it in Code.

Comment: I don't think if there is such possibility with plain VS Code ... so, is this a question about what extension should you use? Then it seems to be off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the C# extension for VS code? If not, downloading and installing that does the job.

I personally use the OmniSharp C# extension, and it does what you're asking for.

Comment: I use that as well: ms-dotnettools.csharp. But it doesn't show these suggestions in the Problems window. Only warnings and errors. I think that this setting is related: Suppress Hidden Diagnostics. And it's turned off, so they shouldn't be suppressed. But I can't see them anyway.

Comment: Okay, now it works. I forgot to restart VS Code after I unticked Suppress Hidden Diagnostics. (For some reason it was on by default for me)